# how convert a new string date into a date with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a string of new date value. How can I covert it into my expected output using vanilla JavaScript.

```
let str = "Sun May 01 2022 20:30:20 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)"
```

expected output: `May 01, 2022`

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your JavaScript code that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself.  There are a TON of similar questions on this site.  What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/parsing-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDate="Sun May 01 2022 20:30:20 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)";
var dateArrays=myDate.split(" ");
var newDate=dateArrays[1]+" "+dateArrays[2]+", "+dateArrays[3]
console.log(newDate);
```